# Trigger event when SocketIO closes a room that empties automatically

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io

Is there anyway to listen for an event relating to when a room closes automatically by the adapter? I've been looking for awhile and can't seem to find any solution.

Use case: When a room empties on socketio, I want to trigger an event that will delete a key in an attached redis cache.

Combing through the repo doesn't seem to give much in regards to this, so this may count as a feature request?

The only this I thought of is subscribing to the redis cache that socketio uses for its own message handling and listening for `DEL` commands with a `SUBSCRIBE` and parsing the channel that's been deleted, but I'm not sure how to attach to that specific redis client.

Thanks